# Compiling my first DSL in Delite

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, sbt, dsl

I am trying to follow the tutorial on compiling a simple DSL using Delite+LMS. I compiled LMS and Delite succesfully. Now, following this tutorial closely: http://stanford-ppl.github.io/Delite/myfirstdsl.html I run into problems when I try to build my profiling dsl. It seems that the compiler cannot find the delite-collection classes:

```
felix@felix-UX32VD:~/Documents/phd/delite/Delite$ sbt compile
Loading /home/felix/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash
[info] Loading project definition from /home/felix/Documents/phd/delite/Delite/project
[info] Set current project to delite (in build file:/home/felix/Documents/phd/delite/Delite/)
[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources to /home/felix/Documents/phd/delite/Delite/dsls/profiling/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/felix/Documents/phd/delite/Delite/dsls/profiling/src/example/profiling/Profile.scala:7: object DeliteCollection is not a member of package ppl.delite.framework.datastruct.scala
[error] import ppl.delite.framework.datastruct.scala.DeliteCollection
[error]        ^
[error] /home/felix/Documents/phd/delite/Delite/dsls/profiling/src/example/profiling/Profile.scala:69: not found: type ScalaGenProfileArrayOps
[error]   with ScalaGenDeliteOps with ScalaGenProfileOps with ScalaGenProfileArrayOps
[error]      

                                             ^
```

Does someone have some insights to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: simply wrong imports or missing class on the classpath

Comment: The source code is a duplicate from the tutorial. I guess the problem is that I'm a complete sbt-noob :) Can you tell me where/how to fix this stuff in SBT?

Comment: Did you add the dependency on your libraries?

Comment: In Delite/project/Build.scala I have defined:    lazy val profiling = Project("profiling", file("dsls/profiling"), settings = virtBuildSettings) dependsOn(framework). When I inspect the folder "Delite/framework/src/ppl/delite/framework/datastruct/scala" where I expect the DeliteCollection.scala file should be, it is not to be found. Is it possible that the files have moved since this tutorial was written?

Comment: Edmondo1984> As I am running this from inside the Delite git-hub clone, I was assuming that the project itself would automatically be a dependency. Is this wrong?

Comment: I think you have some confusion about how dependency management works. See answer

Comment: After an e-mail correspondence with Kevin Brown, it seems that the tutorial was indeed outdated (i.e. DeliteCollection.scala was not available in that package anymore). Will give it a try with an updated repo here: https://github.com/stanford-ppl/Delite/tree/develop/framework/delite-test/tests/ppl/tests/scalatest/firstdsl

Comment: this doesn't change what I am telling you in my answer. Don't write your code inside the Delite project. Compile it, publish, and reference it as a dependency. This is a good practice in any programming language, any build system, etc etc

Comment: Sure, I was just following the tutorial to get a "HelloWorld" going. I quote from the tutorial link:

"First, start from the base directory of the Delite distribution, and create a source directory for our project:
mkdir -p dsls/profiling/src".

Will of course move to best practice as soon as I get _anything_ working.

Comment: I suggest you'd better make things right from the beginning :))

Answer (score 1):

From SBT manual:

> Library dependencies can be added in two ways:
>
> - unmanaged dependencies are jars dropped into the lib directory
> - managed dependencies are configured in the build definition and downloaded
>   automatically from repositories (through Apache Ivy, exactly like Maven)

In any case, adding code inside a framework project is a bad idea, because you will have to change the build process (for example, adding an extra module). In addition, you might have to recompile all the code of the framework and this would be very slow.

The right way to make your code depending on a framework is:

- Reference the library as a managed dependency available in some kind of repository (best solution).
- Copy the jar inside the lib folder of your project and add it as an unmanaged dependency.

Since apparently Delite is not available on any Ivy repo, the best approach is to clone the Git repo and publish it locally. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Publishing.html

> Publishing Locally
>
> The publishLocal command will publish to the local
> Ivy repository. By default, this is in ${user.home}/.ivy2/local. Other
> projects on the same machine can then list the project as a
> dependency. For example, if the SBT project you are publishing has
> configuration parameters like:
>
> name := 'My Project'
>
> organization := 'org.me'
>
> version :=
> '0.1-SNAPSHOT'
>
> Then another project can depend on it:
>
> libraryDependencies += "org.me" %% "my-project" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT"